# Problem with region plot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, regions

I have a function `f[x,y]` involving numerical integration. It returns values for any values of x and y well, and if I want to plot its as a function of one of arguments with fixed remained argument it goes well.

However, when I try to compute `RegionPlot[f[x,y]>=1, {x,x0,x1},{y,y0,y1}]`, it returns some number of errors like

> `NIntegrate::inumr:` The integrand `0.0019697 (-E^(-((1.15633*10^18
>   10^Uee mN <<1>>)/EN))+E^(-((9.63608*10^17 10^Uee mN
>   InterpolatingFunction[(0.01   35.92),<<3>>,{Automatic}][mN])/EN)))
>   If[EN>=39\[And]EN<=117,Interpolation[hnlfromwenergydistribution,InterpolationOrder->6][EN],0]`
>   has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
>   region with boundaries (Indeterminate Indeterminate).

and after all, instead of region plot the output is just `False`. What can be a reason for this, and how to avoid this?

Comment: Difficult to assist without `f[x,y]`.

Comment: Try defining `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := ...` instead of `f[x_, y_] := ...`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have non-numeric values like `Uee` and `mN` in the plotted function. Try evaluating `f[x,y]` for some values of $x$ and $y$, and if it does not return a number, you can not plot it.